# Add "New Journal entry" to "Home (Mail)" ribbon tab in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013, ribbon

In Outlook 2010, I had a custom group in my Home (Mail) tab on the ribbon, which had (among other commands) "New Journal entry" in it. Everything worked fine.

I had to upgrade to Outlook 2013, and now it seems I can only add "New Item" to the Home tab on the ribbon, which is keyed to which Home tab is currently active. This means "New Mail" when in the Mail view, "New Journal entry" when in the Journal view, etc. But I want a "New Journal entry" in the Mail view, just like I had it in 2010. Is that possible?